# Inline Block Display Issue

Tags: css, alignment

I am creating a dashboard and in the dashboard I got two boxes that I wanted have in the same level at the top. I am using the display "inline-block" to group them in boxes; however, the result is different instead the bottom part is in the same level but the top is not. See screenshot below:

https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/8e14/xdh672yojc8owe86g.jpg

I set the height of each box to "auto". You can see on the screenshot that the first box is not aligned equally to the second box, is there a way to have the two boxes in the same level or aligned equally at the top? I tried using table-cell display but it has compatibility issue on other browsers such as IE. Thanks

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: @nagatron2 without your code, we can't help you...

Comment: The code "verical-align: top;" did the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `verical-align: top;` CSS property on the element which contains your inline-block elements. ;)